# LINQ Error The type is not supported in aggregation operations

Tags: linq

I have LINQ code and I receive the following error: `System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The type 'ObjectMgmt' is not supported in aggregation operations.`

```
(from cinnost in edc.CinnostSOPs
 where cinnost.LegislativneVyznamna == true &&
       cinnost.ObjektId == objektid
 select (from o in edc.PlanRealizaces
         where o.CinnostSOPIdSOP == cinnost.IdSOP &&
               o.DatumPlatnosti <= DateTime.Now &&
               o.Provest == true &&
               o.DatumProvedeni == null
         orderby o.DatumPlatnosti descending
         select new ObjectMgmt
         {
             Datum = (DateTime.Now.Date - o.DatumPlatnosti.Value).TotalDays
         }).Max(m => m)).ToList<ObjectMgmt>();
```

Comment: Wow, that query is completely illegible. Can you read this code yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error you get tells you that `ObjectMgmt` can not be used as the source of an aggregation. This happens because `Max` requires that the `ObjectMgmt` type implements `IComparable`.

After formatting your query to make it more readable it seems that you want to find the `ObjectMgmt` instance where `Datum` has the maximum value.

Since you already ordered the values descending by `DatumPlatnosti` you know that the `ObjectMgmt` instances are ordered by increasing `Datum` values. Therefore you don't need an aggregation at all. Just take the last element of the sequence (I would however order ascending and then take the first element).

```
(from cinnost in edc.CinnostSOPs
 where cinnost.LegislativneVyznamna == true &&
       cinnost.ObjektId == objektid
 select (from o in edc.PlanRealizaces
         where o.CinnostSOPIdSOP == cinnost.IdSOP &&
               o.DatumPlatnosti <= DateTime.Now &&
               o.Provest == true &&
               o.DatumProvedeni == null
         orderby o.DatumPlatnosti
         select new ObjectMgmt
         {
             Datum = (DateTime.Now.Date - o.DatumPlatnosti.Value).TotalDays
         }).First()).ToList<ObjectMgmt>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The message speaks of an aggregate. The only aggregate I see is the `Max` call. This is the hint needed to debug the problem.

You care calculating the max of a sequence of `ObjectMgmt` instances which is obviously not possible. Change that to what you really meant.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `ObjectMgmt` objects have only one property filled by query: `Datum`, change your `Max` call to get max of `Datum`, not the `ObjectMgmt` itself:

```
(from cinnost in edc.CinnostSOPs
 where cinnost.LegislativneVyznamna == true &&
       cinnost.ObjektId == objektid
 select (from o in edc.PlanRealizaces
         where o.CinnostSOPIdSOP == cinnost.IdSOP &&
               o.DatumPlatnosti <= DateTime.Now &&
               o.Provest == true &&
               o.DatumProvedeni == null
         orderby o.DatumPlatnosti descending
         select new ObjectMgmt
         {
             Datum = (DateTime.Now.Date - o.DatumPlatnosti.Value).TotalDays
         }).Max(m => m.Datum)).ToList<ObjectMgmt>();
```